# Unexpected type name 'BOOL': expected expression in iOS SDK 6.1 (Device)

Tags: ios, objective-c

iOS application for Simulator builds fine. However, when I try to build for device, compilation fails on @YES and @NO literals. We use iOS 6.1 as build SDK, but have 5.1 in reserve. iPad's OS version is 6.1.3. Is there anything I'm missing what could cause this to fail?

```
Fragment from build log: /Applications/Xcode-4.6.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
    iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/include/objc/objc.h:50:26
    : note: expanded from macro 'YES'
#define YES             (BOOL)1
```

Is there any reason why 5.1 SDK is picked up in the build?

Deployment target is 5.0, but changing it to 6.1 doesn't fix the issue. Xcode version: 4.6 (4H127)

Yes, I know that going with @(YES) and @(NO) instead would fix this, but this is so 5.0 solution.

Comment: i remember seeing something about this once, try going @(YES) instead

Comment: @MarceloFabri Updated in question - 4.6 (4H127).

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project and delete DerivedData?

Comment: Could there be header imports in a circle? Are you importing `objc.h` headers somewhere manually? Or redefining `(BOOL)`? Try to check where exactly the compilation fails. Or maybe non-standard compiler arguments? Or your own preprocessor directive colliding with preprocessor directives in Apple headers?

Comment: Sulthan -  Nope. This code compiled fine two weeks ago. See that it builds fine for Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brutal answer:

Installing new Xcode and removing no longer (at this point) 5.1 SDK fixed the problem. Hard to say what exactly happened, but upgrading your tools to the freshest version is recommended.